# How to use saveas() to save a .mat or .txt in specific directory on ubunto

Tags: matlab, save, save-as

I have tried:

```
saveas(keys ,keyname);
save(keys ,keyname ,'-mat');
save(keys ,keyname);
```

where `keys` is a 3006x4104 matrix of the class double.
I tried to use some casting so I would save it as txt file

for `keyname` I tried - `./newdronephotos/1880key.mat`
and `newdronephotos/1880key.mat`.

It's not working.
In particular, when I'm trying `saveas(keys ,keyname);`
it's starting to do some processes and then print the error message:
`Error using saveas (line 88)
Simulink object array must be a vector`

Comment: Look at the help file for `save`. In which order do the inputs go? In which order do you have them?  `saveas` is not for saving matrices...

Comment: Obviously, I tried to use the help file before I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just succeeded to solve my own problem.
The function save() expect to have a string of the name of the desired variable.
For example:
Instead of - 
save(keyname ,keys);
I needed to write-
save(keyname ,'keys');